# Wierd thing while using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to detect a pattern using regex but I have a weird problem.
That's the pattern -

```
"/sub\{(.*)\}/i"
```

I'm using it like this:

```
if(preg_match("/sub\{(.*)\}/i",$item))
{
    $sub = explode("|",$item);
    $sub_name = explode("{",$sub[0]);
    $sub_name = $sub_name[1];
    ...
}
```

Here is the string -

```
sub{selected posts|post[1]}
```

Well, the string above is good,but when i'm adding another item like this -

```
sub{selected posts|post[1],post[2]}
```

Edit - The problem was with the format of my menu, I exploded the "," sign while having it in the sub section
Thanks everyone!

Comment: can you display the full code used for this?

Comment: I added the relative code.
And what do you mean @Omega?

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"? The regex matches both strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the curly brackets like this:

```
"/sub\{(.*)\}/i"
```

Comment: I'd think the same thing, but then I wonder why it worked for the first input.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression looks fine, is there maybe a newline in the part you're trying to math? If so, add the `m` and `s` modifiers to get `"/sub{(.*)}/ims"`

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Mike wrote, make sure to run the string through [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape any regex characters.